# Android market icon application

Tags: android, google-play

In the web android market, when I search my application I see my personal icon, but when I search my application from my phone my application has the default icon. I would like that icon to be my launch icon. What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch icon and label is defined in the manifest in this line:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You must put the launch icon in the res/drawable directory (preferably different resolutions under the different resolution directories).  So in the above example you must have an icon.png file in res/drawable, or an icon.png in each of res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-ldpi.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html for the icon design guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your app icon in each drawable resource folder in your app this way each screen will have its on icon for its screen density.. And make sure in your AndroidManifest you change the Icon from the default icon to your icon you want.

Comment: I put the new icon just in one of the three drawable folder. This was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Figure. As i have ran into this mistake =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your icon in app resources folder and in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: in the menu my applicaton launcher has my personal icon <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can use this program to change the images for Android =>
[Android Icon Maker](http://www.redrails.com.br/2011/09/android-icon-maker/)